# Selenium Python error DesiredCapabilities

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Some of my bots have this error today

```
Selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find dict 'desiredCapabilities'
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.22000 x86_64)
```

I've already tried some possibilities that I read in forums and in the selenium documentation. Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

get = "198.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"

.
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME()
capabilities['platform'] = "WINDOWS"
capabilities['version'] = "10"


driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=capabilities
                         command_executor=get)
```

This problem occurs even in simpler code like:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = (way\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('stackoverflow.com')
```

Does anyone know any documentation or solution for this problem?

Comment: I am having the same error. Upto recently this was working.

Comment: I am facing this issue. @Cthaeh, can you explain how you fixed the issue?

Comment: my problem was with chromium and the driver. there was a version incompatibility between them, I fixed it by upgrading the driver version.